# Advanced transparency in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

Im looking for a way to create form(s) similar in style to the following two..

Ive played with transparency keys, the windows API, but have not successfully done this in Windows Forms.

*[broken image]*

what im looking for with this post is any references to articles explaining how this can be done, or some code examples. -- but i will accept any kind of input.

I would use Windows Vista/7 Areo glass if it didnt have such horrible alpha-blending issues.

Comment: Is it possible that these so-called "alpha-blending issues" are actually due to your lack of understanding rather than a fatal flaw in the Windows codebase?

Comment: @David: Quite possibly. but i had been having some issues, and did some research and had found in an article someone suggesting that WinForms had some alpha blending issues, and it made sense so i just assumed...

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to adjust the [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) of the Form.

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/transparent_controls.aspx) example

Comment: that would change the entire form though

Comment: Sigh, this is quite obviously the correct answer.  The title bar of the base window clearly shows signs of Opacity.  There's another toplevel borderless window sandwiched on top of it that uses TransparencyKey.  Allowing drawing opaque as well as partially transparent with an alpha brush.  No problem in Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link below for an article about how to find a way to show Windows standard controls on layered windows. It provides both Native MFC and WinForms source code.

[Cool, Semi-transparent and Shaped Dialogs with Standard Controls for Windows 2000 and Above](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SemiTranDlgWithCtrls.aspx)

> **Using the Code in WinForms/.NET**
>
> **First Step:**
>
> Copy files in the /Src/*.* directory to your project.
>
> **Second Step**
>
> You need an image file to be the dialog background. You'd better
>   choose PNG or TIFF which support alpha channel.
>
> **Final Step**
>
> Replace the dialog base class from `Form` to `ImageDlgBase`.
>
> ```
> public partial class Form2 : CoolImageDlg.ImageDlgBase {
>     public Form2()
>     {
>         base.DlgBgImg = ImgDlgSample.Properties.Resources.DemoDlgBg2;
>         //......
>      } 
> }
> ```

See the example code in the article.

Comment: if WPF is an option, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the DWM to extend the "glass" area of your window. 
See Figure 10 in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx)

Or, by using DirectX, you can get [this effect](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/umvistad3d.aspx). Don't think you can with winforms, though.

Comment: I realize, but that has some major alpha-blending issues iirc.

Comment: @Tommy: sorry, now I see you already knew about the glass API. Do check the link I added.

Comment: looks interesting - will research into if this integrates with .net at all soon..